# Appending variables in R

Tags: r

So I have this output in R, just random numbers like this

```
1 2 3 4 5
0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5
0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05
```

I want to append "Value" "Median" "Min" to this so it would like this

```
Value 1 2 3 4 5
Median 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5
Min 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05
```

I'm not sure how to do this...I can do it if its numbers but cant do it with words
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Either `paste()`:

```
> paste("Value",1,2,3,4,5)
[1] "Value 1 2 3 4 5"
```

Or `cat()`:

```
> cat("Value",1,2,3,4,5)
Value 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant add a text variable to the start of your number vector, because the number vector doesnt allow some values to be characters. You can name the three vectors, the appropriate name, and then join them in a data.frame, for easy display.

```
value  <-  c(1,2,3)
median <-  c(0.1,0.2,0.3)
Min    <-  c(0.01,0.02,0.03)
x      <-  data.frame(value,median,min)
```

Outputs:

```
x
  value median  Min
1     1    0.1 0.01
2     2    0.2 0.02
3     3    0.3 0.03
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it as close to your definition/format as possible try this:

```
row1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
row2 = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5)
row3 = c(0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05)   
rows = rbind(row1,row2,row3)
rownames(rows) = c('Value','Median','Mean')
rows

       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
Value  1.00 2.00 3.00 4.00 5.00
Median 0.10 0.20 0.30 0.40 0.50
Mean   0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05
```